# active_admin - display a list of items that belongs to another item

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I am trying to display somehow the `line items` for the `order` in the active_admin `order show page`, no luck..

here are the relations between models:

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  # ...
  validates :name, :address, :email, :presence => true
  validates :pay_type, :inclusion => PAYMENT_TYPES
end
```

**line_item.rb**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end

end
```

**active_admin order.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do

  show do
    attributes_table :name, :email, :address, :pay_type, :created_at, :updated_at
  end
end
```

**active_admin line_item.rb**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end

end
```

when I click show order, it must display the items for this order.. In application's show file I did it with

```
<%= render @order.line_items %>
```

**_line_items.html.erb**

```
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
    <tr id="current_item">
  <% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

and the items are in the page, but in Active_Admin I don't know how to make it work.. Please help. Thank you for your time.

**Solved**

Thanks to bruno077  I managed to finally get the line_items in the order show_page in ActiveAdmin

```
 show do |order|

  panel "Customer details" do
    attributes_table_for order, :first_name, :last_name, :card_type, :created_at, :ip_address
  end

  panel("Products for this order") do
    table_for(order.line_items) do
      column "Product" do |item| 
        item.product.title
      end
      column "Price" do |item| 
        item.product.price
      end
      column "Quantity" do |item| 
        item.quantity
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I got the ID of the product for now, but it's not far from here to get what I want. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  show do |order|
    div do      
      panel("Items") do
        table_for(order.line_items) do
          column :quantity
          column "Title" do |i| 
            i.product.title
          end
          column "Price" do |i| 
            number_to_current(i.total_price)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Another unrelated example which might give you a hint:

```
  # => Show
  show :title => :date do |gallery|
    panel "Galería" do
      attributes_table_for gallery, :name, :description, :date
    end

    panel "Fotos" do
      table_for(gallery.gallery_files) do
        column "Título", :title
        column "Fecha", :date
        column "Foto" do |image|
          image_tag image.file.url(:thumb).to_s
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting kEND
          column 'title' { product.title }  there are 4 errors of this kind, 1 for each "{"  could you take a look at it please? Thank you very much at least for trying.

Comment: it creates the columns, fot this thing only I vote +1, this was reallly helpfull, but I really need to get this relations to work in Active Admin.

Comment: I think that maybe {} notation might not work with ActiveAdmin, I'll update the answer.

Comment: well, it shows the title of this columns, but still no items are displayed.. :(  p.s. no errors in terminal

Comment: where did you get the second example from? I might take a look at how models are related to each other

Comment: It's my code, I'll share with you the models in a gist in a moment.

Comment: Here's some sample code that works in my application: https://gist.github.com/2288283

Comment: thanks bruno077, your asnwer moved me from a deapoint. Tnank you.

Comment: How can we do this for index page?